# What is the most efficient algorithm or data structure for finding correlations between lists?

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures, graph, combinations

### List 1

- ItemA
- ItemB
- ItemC

### List 2

- ItemD
- ItemE
- ItemA

### List 3

- ItemA
- ItemB
- ItemG

In the above example, List 1 shows there is a correlation between ItemA, ItemB and ItemC. List 2 shows correlation between ItemD, ItemE and Item A, and so on... There is also correlation for ItemA and ItemB to ItemC in List 1 and for ItemA and ItemB to ItemG in List 3. Another example is List 2 showing coorelation from ItemD and ItemE to ItemA, and so on...

Basically I want to efficiently store and query these correlations when there can be 1 million+ lists and up to 10,000 or more unique items. The upper bound is n factorial for storage (since this is basically combinations) and that is not feasiable.

Looked up possible algorithms on google.

Comment: What did you find about possible algorithms ? What do you mean exactly by correlation ? It is the [Statistical definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation) ? It feels like giving us the context and what you want to do would really help here. [See XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Also, the explanation about the example is hard to follow, as it's all text. Maybe try to reformat like `[A,B] ->[C]`, `[A] -> [B,C]` ?

Comment: Please define what YOU mean by 'correlation'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.